# Use a different template file if use is on a mobile device

Tags: 6, theming

I currently am using `page-front.tpl.php` to display my *Blog* content type in a View. I want to use a different template if the user is on a mobile device, and have them either redirected to the mobile view, or have the Drupal theme layer use a different template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to setup some method that will detect whether the use is coming from a mobile device and than add a function in your template.php file to switch to your mobile template.

For the mobile detection, there are a number of modules available for this but for this specific use case, I would recommend [Mobile Switch](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_switch) because it provides a specific variable you can use for testing in your theme (others like Mobile Tools might as well, this is just one I've used before). From documentation:

```
Development with Mobile Switch.

The module provides four system variables:

1. mobile_switch_ismobiledevice
2. mobile_switch_istablet
3. mobile_switch_ismobiletheme
4. theme_mobile
```

From here, you just need to add a [template suggestion to your theme](http://drupal.org/node/223440) through the preprocess_page function using this variable, ex:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  global $mobile_switch_ismobiledevice;

  if ((request_path() == 'YOUR_PATH') && $mobile_switch_ismobiledevice) {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'mobile-YOURTEMPLATE';
  }

}
```

This method assumes you want to specifically switch between two template files, if you would prefer to use a separate mobile theme, than the Mobile Switch or Mobile Tools module have configuration options to help you do this.

Comment: Note for Drupal 7: use `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__YOURTEMPLATE';`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a combination of [Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) and [Mobile Switch](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_switch).

**Browscap**

> Browscap provides an improved version of PHP's get_browser() function.
>
> The get_browser() function can be used to tell what a visitor's
>   browser is capable of [...]

**Mobile Switch**

> The Mobile Switch module provides a simple automatic theme switch
>   functionality for mobile devices, detected by Browscap or Mobile
>   Detect.

If you're looking to do it through code (e.g. you would prefer to put something in your existing `tpl.php`) then Browscap provides a handy [`browscap_get_browser()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!browscap!browscap.module/function/browscap_get_browser/6) function which is a kind of replacement for the PHP function [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), so you could do something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
$browser = browscap_get_browser();

if ($browser == "MOBILE_BROWSER") {
 print $MY_MOBILE_VIEW;
}
else {
 print $MY_DESKTOP_VIEW;
}
```